# How do I specify the search type in Google Auto Complete?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently getting this error while trying to pass the Place paramerer to the Google Maps auto complete view controller.

> Default argument value of type 'String' cannot be converted to type
>   'GMSAutocompleteViewController.Type'

```
func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController.Type = kGMSPlaceTypeLocality, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace) {

    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .City    
}
```

I am following the documentation and it seems to be telling me to add the type to the AutoCompleteViewController and pass the parameters of the type which I did. You can check out the documentation here if you that will help. https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2

Anybody know why this would be happening? Just getting familiar with Google APIs. Just tried adding a filter and still have no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`GMSAutocompleteViewController.Type = kGMSPlaceTypeLocality` looks wrong to me.

The autocomplete filter types are different to place types, which is why you get a compile error if you try to combine them.

Answer (score -1):

As shown in the steps to [add a full-screen control](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_full-screen_control) to your app, handling of user's selection in the `didAutocompleteWithPlace` delegate method should be like this:

```
func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWithPlace place: GMSPlace){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

More information and helpful examples can be found in [Place Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601172/how-do-i-specify-the-search-type-in-google-auto-complete).

Comment: I am looking to filter the place type that is searched instead of everything listed under types.